# Multiple timepickers on same page

Tags: javascript, php, timepicker

I have two timepicker.js input fields in same page, well one is on include but nevertheless 
code is: 
One input filed is:

````
<input class="w3-input w3-border w3-light-grey" type="text" id="timeroc" name="timeroc" placeholder="Kliknite..." style="width: 97%;" />```

     var timepicker = new TimePicker("timeroc", {
      lang: 'en',
      theme: 'dark'
    });
    timepicker.on('change', function(evt) {

      var value = (evt.hour || '00') + ':' + (evt.minute || '00');
      evt.element.value = value;
});
````

second is:

```
<input class="w3-input w3-border w3-light-grey" type="text" id="time" name="time" placeholder="Kliknite..." style="width: 97%;" />
var timepicker = new TimePicker("time", {
      lang: 'en',
      theme: 'dark'
    });
    timepicker.on('change', function(evt) {

      var value = (evt.hour || '00') + ':' + (evt.minute || '00');
      evt.element.value = value;

    });
```

two input fields have different id's, one is time second is timeroc from example. I tried changing numerous things in code one stops working and other puts time in both elements. I tried putting both codes in function with different names and calls to different classes but still one just stops working with no console errors. 
Can someone suggest the second script for second input filed that I should try.

EDIT 
Found it, unbelievable, needs to loaded once with ['field1', 'field2'], I'm really sorry for wasting your time, thank you tho.
https://github.com/jonataswalker/timepicker.js

Comment: please add all code or better add a snippet, including html elements.

Comment: I edited my post to include current state.

Comment: what specific lib are you using?

Comment: also `new TimePicker("time"), {` is not going to work, need to remove the `)`

Comment: I know it was i typo, im chaning thing all the time, doesn't work. I can not find the link to it i include it local, trying to find the page but i lost it.

Comment: Does the issue persist if you change the second `var timepicker` to `var timepicker2` ? Obviously changing `timepicker` var to `timepicker2` on the eventlistener declaration too

Comment: Yes, tried that, still loads on one and put into another to, on that other doesn't work, just loads...

Comment: Im geting now  active is undefined in timepicker.js active.hour = this$1.getHour(evt.target);

Comment: Yeah something wrong on developer side...

Comment: Can you provide the link to the lib you're using and provide a full working snippet to get more info please?

Comment: OK i find a link in js itself as i load it locally https://github.com/jonataswalker/timepicker.js

Comment: Found it, unbelievable, needs to loaded once with ['field1', 'field2'], I'm really sorry for wasting your time, thank you tho.

Comment: Ok, the issue is because your using `var timepicker = ` twice, the second overwrites the first instance.. though see the [target](https://github.com/jonataswalker/timepicker.js#target-can-be) option in the docs, it can be a `.class` no need to repeat same code if its same for both timepickers.

Comment: I actually tried changing one var timepicker into var timepicker2 as even @JoelBonetR mentioned and some other things still didn't help. Also tried with classes in code as it is and even putting into function that targets only class, still nothing. Problem was i lost github link to lib, as you where asking for it went into local file and find it there luckily.

Comment: Lol...ok. if you tried to separate the scope of the two functions and setting different names for every instantiation it may be a bug or lack of documentation